# Bios update fixing windows issues: skip it or do it?

Tags: updates, dell, bios, xps

I have Ubuntu running on Dell xps 13 9360.

Ubuntu Software Update is telling me there is an update for my BIOS, the update is [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=G05NR).

In the link this is reported:

```
Fixes & Enhancements
Fixes:
- Fixed incorrect Windows operating system logon message.
```

Since I don't have Windows installed, should I skip this update or is it better to install it anyway?

Answer (score 5):

Skip the BIOS update. If it isn't broken don't fix it. You can put a package named for example *package-name* on hold with the following command:

```
echo package-name hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

This command will hold back *package-name* from being updated.